# InnoSetup, prevent installation if any task is selected

Tags: installation, inno-setup, pascal, pascalscript

My inno script has two tasks:

```
[Tasks]
Name: client; Description: Install FTP client
Name: server; Description: Install FTP server
```

I would like to deny the installation in a non-intrusive way if any task is selected, for non.intrusive I mean for example enabling/disabling the "next" button when one of both tasks are checked, no advertising messagbe-box.

I'm not sure if innosetup has a parameter or a "check" function to do this in a simple way

How I could do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to do what you want *natively* in Inno Setup. You will need to do it from code by yourself.

You can cheat here a bit by using the [`WizardSelectedTasks`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_wizardselectedtasks) function. This function returns a comma separated list of selected task names (or descriptions), and so it returns an empty string when no task is selected. The rest is about binding task list `OnClickCheck` event, and updating the next button enable state and writing a piece of code to initialize the next button state:

```
[Setup]
AppName=My Program
AppVersion=1.5
DefaultDirName={pf}\My Program

[Tasks]
Name: client; Description: Install FTP client
Name: server; Description: Install FTP server

[Code]
// helper function
function IsAnyTaskSelected: Boolean;
begin
  Result := WizardSelectedTasks(False) <> '';
end;

// event handler for setting the next button initial state when
// entering the tasks page
procedure CurPageChanged(CurPageID: Integer);
begin
  if CurPageID = wpSelectTasks then
    WizardForm.NextButton.Enabled := IsAnyTaskSelected;
end;

// method of the task list check click event
procedure TasksListClickCheck(Sender: TObject);
begin
  WizardForm.NextButton.Enabled := IsAnyTaskSelected;
end;

procedure InitializeWizard;
begin
  WizardForm.TasksList.OnClickCheck := @TasksListClickCheck;
end;
```

Comment: I don't know if you are an official InnoSetup developer but you demonstrate awesome knowledges about InnoSetup internals as always. I could be tried this by my own for 6 months and never find a solution, thanks so much for the help and for be here helping innosetup coders.

Comment: You're welcome, and thanks! I'm not IS contributor (I have a few ideas to work on but have no extra time unfortunately). But you can find [Jordan Russell](http://stackoverflow.com/users/432561/jordan-russell) and [Martijn Laan](http://stackoverflow.com/users/301485/mlaan) here on SO.