# InnoSetup, Convert tasks to Radiobuttons?

Tags: windows, installation, inno-setup, pascal, pascalscript

I've asked something similar before in this question: [InnoSetup, prevent installation if any task is selected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27805898/innosetup-prevent-installation-if-any-task-is-selected)

But this situation is a little bit different because only one of both tasks should be selected, then how I could transform the selection beetwen two tasks to two new selectable Radiobuttons?

PS: If that is not the best approach then please suggest me another.

An image to explain:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the [`exclusive`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=taskssection&anchor=exclusive) flag:

```
[Tasks]
Name: hidden; Description: Hidden mode; GroupDescription: Installation Mode; Flags: exclusive
Name: visible; Description: Visible mode; GroupDescription: Installation Mode; Flags: exclusive
```

Comment: Amazing I didn't know the usage of exclusive flags, it seems to do exactlly what I suggested (it transforms the tasks into radiobuttons), but then how I could set the "visible" task as the default selected task in the installer UI  instead of the "hidden" task? (for silent installation for example)

Comment: Maybe adding an "unchecked" flag to "hidden" task will do the trick?

Comment: Yes. That is correct. Anyway, it seems that you're developing the UI in favor of silent installation. That's not a good way. That logic should be separated, I mean, you shouldn't set a task to the state required by the silent installation. You can do that if you drive your setup settings also by the `WizardSilent` function. For example, if you would like to make your setup uninstallable when setup runs silently, or the `hidden` task is selected, write `Uninstallable=WizardSilent or not not IsTaskSelected('hidden')`.