# Inno Setup: turning exclusive Tasks into radio boxes

Tags: installation, windows-installer, inno-setup

I'm working on an Inno Setup installer that has 4 radio boxes to let the user select which "flavor" they want to install. The documentation left me confused; should I use Tasks, Types, or Components for that?

It seems Tasks have radio-button behavior built-in: when the `exclusive` flag is set, only one of the tasks can be selected at a time. That's exactly what I want. So I have this code:

```
[Tasks]
Name: variant-a; Description: "A"; GroupDescription: "Variant"; Flags: exclusive
Name: variant-b; Description: "B"; GroupDescription: "Variant"; Flags: exclusive unchecked
Name: variant-c; Description: "C"; GroupDescription: "Variant"; Flags: exclusive unchecked
Name: variant-d; Description: "D"; GroupDescription: "Variant"; Flags: exclusive unchecked
```

How can I make the radio buttons show up? And how do I get the value of the Task that was chosen (e.g. `"variant-a"`)?

Comment: According to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27981941/innosetup-convert-tasks-to-radiobuttons just using `exclusive` should be enough.

Comment: I do not get your question. Your code is ok, except that task `Name` cannot contain a dash, what you will easily find by just trying to compile your code. Once I remove the dashes, the tasks show up as radio buttons: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JXOT0.png - So what do you ask for?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl : I don't think to show the radio buttons is the problem for OP but next is **"And how do I get the value of the Task that was chosen"**

Comment: @moskito-x Maybe. But question title says something completely else. + And for the other question, we need to know how/what for the OP want to use the selected value.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Are you saying just having these 5 lines of code in the file should be enough to make the UI with radio boxes show up? Because that's not working for me. As for the value I want to get, it could be the `Name` or anything else really, as long as I can distinguish between the four. It would be easiest to get a working example.

Comment: Yes, exactly those lines make the radio buttons appear as shown on my screenshots. If it does not work for you, we need [mcve]. + As for the value: But where/how/for what do you need to distinguish them?

Comment: Hello Boget @MathiasBynens : Can you please look at my answer !??

Answer (score 4):

**The best is to use an existing script and see how it works**

> The documentation left me confused; should I use Tasks, Types, or
>   Components for that?

The added code parts have both : Task and Components
So decide what is more useful for your project.

**In the `examples` directory are many useful examples that are well suited to respond to user input.**

- Copy the ..:...\Inno Setup 5\Examples\CodeExample1.iss to CodeExample1_ex.iss.
- Open the copied file and insert the following code fragments.

---

Search for 
`OutputDir=userdocs:Inno Setup Examples Output`

Insert below

```
//OutputDir=userdocs:Inno Setup Examples Output

[Tasks]
Name: variant_a; Description: "A"; GroupDescription: "Variant"; Components: main\a; Flags: exclusive
Name: variant_b; Description: "B"; GroupDescription: "Variant"; Components: main\b; Flags: exclusive unchecked
Name: variant_c; Description: "C"; GroupDescription: "Variant"; Components: main\c; Flags: exclusive unchecked
Name: variant_d; Description: "D"; GroupDescription: "Variant"; Components: main\d; Flags: exclusive unchecked

; Disabled we need it later -----------------------------------------------------
;Name: variant_a; Description: "A"; GroupDescription: "Variant"; Flags: exclusive
;Name: variant_b; Description: "B"; GroupDescription: "Variant"; Flags: exclusive unchecked
;Name: variant_c; Description: "C"; GroupDescription: "Variant"; Flags: exclusive unchecked
;Name: variant_d; Description: "D"; GroupDescription: "Variant"; Flags: exclusive

[Types]
Name: "full"; Description: "Full installation"
Name: "compact"; Description: "Compact installation"
Name: "custom"; Description: "Custom installation"; Flags: iscustom

[Components]
Name: "program"; Description: "Program Files"; Types: full compact custom; Flags: fixed
Name: "help"; Description: "Help File"; Types: full
Name: "readme"; Description: "Readme File"; Types: full
Name: "readme\en"; Description: "English"; Flags: exclusive
Name: "readme\de"; Description: "German"; Flags: exclusive
Name: "main"; Description: "variants"; Types: custom
Name: "main\a"; Description: "variant_a"; Types: custom; Flags: exclusive
Name: "main\b"; Description: "variant_b"; Types: custom; Flags: exclusive
Name: "main\c"; Description: "variant_c"; Types: custom full; Flags: exclusive
Name: "main\d"; Description: "variant_d"; Types: custom; Flags: exclusive
```

---

Search for the [Code] and add `I : integer;`

```
[Code]
var
  MyProgChecked: Boolean;
  MyProgCheckResult: Boolean;
  FinishedInstall: Boolean;
  I : integer;
```

---

Search for 
`procedure CurPageChanged(CurPageID: Integer);`

Insert below

```
//procedure CurPageChanged(CurPageID: Integer);
var
Addtxt,WFCaption,WSelCaption : String;
```

---

Search for 
`Log('CurPageChanged(' + IntToStr(CurPageID) + ') called');`

Insert below

```
      //Log('CurPageChanged(' + IntToStr(CurPageID) + ') called');

  if CurPageID = wpSelectComponents then begin
     WFCaption := WizardForm.ComponentsList.ItemCaption[8];
     Addtxt    := ' <---------- If I where you I would take this';
     if Pos(Addtxt,WFCaption) = 0 then WizardForm.ComponentsList.ItemCaption[8] := WFCaption + Addtxt;
  end;

  if CurPageID = wpSelectTasks then
  begin
     { Only now is the TasksList populated }
     if WizardForm.TasksList.Items.Count = 2 then begin
        WSelCaption := Copy(WizardForm.TasksList.ItemCaption[1],1,2); //else 
        if Pos('C',WizardForm.TasksList.ItemCaption[1]) > 0 then 
           WSelCaption := WSelCaption + ' <-------- Your choice, my favorite, thank you :-)'#13#10+
                                        '                  Not correct? Please go back and change the selection'   else
           WSelCaption := WSelCaption + ' <-------- Your choice : Not correct? Please go back and change the selection';
        WizardForm.TasksList.ItemEnabled[0] := False;
        WizardForm.TasksList.ItemCaption[1] := WSelCaption;
     end else begin
        For I := 1 to WizardForm.TasksList.Items.Count -1 do begin
         if WizardForm.TasksList.Checked[I] then begin
            WizardForm.TasksList.ItemCaption[I] := Copy(WizardForm.TasksList.ItemCaption[I],1,2) +
                                      ' <-------- Your choice : Not correct? Please change the selection';
         end;
        end; // for 
     end;
   end;
```

---

**Next are the constants used for the `CurPageID`**

Example:

```
  if CurPageID = wpSelectComponents  then begin
```

> wpWelcome, wpLicense, wpPassword, wpInfoBefore wpUserInfo,
>   wpSelectDir, wpSelectComponents wpSelectProgramGroup, wpSelectTasks,
>   wpReady wpPreparing, wpInstalling, wpInfoAfter, wpFinished

Change the individual code sections and look at the result.
It is easier and quicker to achieve results that are traceable.

**Version A:**

[image]

and the Task List result.

[image]

Why the trick with the `.ComponentsList`?

- You do not need an extra event.
- It is selected in the `.ComponentsList` and Controlled in the `.Taskslist`.
- If you select nothing the `.Taskslist` is not visible.
- All without extra code in the [Code] section.

---

Now we try **Version B**

Go to the [Task] section and look for
`; Disabled we need it later -----------------------------------------------------`

Disable the first four lines and enable the next four lines.

Search for `procedure CurPageChanged(CurPageID: Integer);`

Add above the Event `WizardForm.TasksList.OnClickCheck := @TaskListClickCheck;`
and the procedure for the `.TasksList`.

**Here goes what you need to capture the selected value.**

How or what you do with the Event `WizardForm.TasksList.OnClickCheck` and the freely selectable name of the function here : `procedure TaskListClickCheck(Sender: TObject);` depends on the requirements you want to achieve.

```
procedure TaskListClickCheck(Sender: TObject);
begin
    For I := 1 to WizardForm.TasksList.Items.Count -1 do begin
        if WizardForm.TasksList.Checked[I] then 
           WizardForm.TasksList.ItemCaption[I] := Copy(WizardForm.TasksList.ItemCaption[I],1,2) +
           ' <-------- Your choice : Not correct? Please change the selection' else
           WizardForm.TasksList.ItemCaption[I] := Copy(WizardForm.TasksList.ItemCaption[I],1,2);
    end;
end;

procedure InitializeWizard();
begin
  WizardForm.TasksList.OnClickCheck := @TaskListClickCheck;
end;

//procedure CurPageChanged(CurPageID: Integer);
```

[image]

- Now we need an event to intercept the selection.
- Without extra code, the selection is always "A".
- At last put before the final list, a little late right?
- The user thought he was almost done!
- The `Name: "main"; Description: "variants"; Types: custom` etc. part of the `.ComponentsList` is useless now. Best to disable it also.

**Where can you find all this information?**

Look at the Inno Setup help.
Search for `WizardForm.TasksList`
There we can see the `property TasksList: **TNewCheckListBox**; read;`
(Used `Properties` are blue)

[image]

So we click on **TNewCheckListBox** and get.

[image]

One or the other we can get a bit easier (direct way: value of a variable).
But here I did not want to make it too complicated and not use directly which only contributes to confusion.

---

**Just using an existing code in an already existing script I do not understand as a code wrighting service.**

To understand it only as an initial aid.